# PHP and Jquery: Always get variable type in front of value

Tags: php, jquery, load

I am trying to pass parameter into php with jquery .load, and always got variable type and value. Please advise:

Jquery Code:

```
 $("#contentDiv").load("' . $killSessionsURL . '", {db:"qa"}); ';
```

PHP Code:

```
echo $_POST['db'];
```

It is supposed to show as below in browser:

```
qa
```

But I got below in browser:

```
 _string(2) "qa"
```

Thanks in advance.

Fei

Comment: Why would you expect anything other than string? Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve] then edit the question with a properly detailed problem description

Comment: echo $_POST['db']; is it fixed in your main script.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone who tried to help. used below code to fix the problem.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
                eval("\$$key = \"$value\";");
}

echo $db
```